# Rotate a GameObject to player position?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2D game and I have a prefab enemy, this enemy is a cannon. I want rotate this cannon when player change position.

The cannon should always rotate to the player position

I'm trying this.

```
// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position);
        if(distance < 10){
            Vector2 dir = player.position - transform.position;
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            Quaternion qto = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);            
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, qto, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

see the result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REeSNKWLvIQ

The cannon isn't rotate to the player position.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is Fine Just Make a Small Change And You Are Good to Go :

```
void Update () {
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(player.position, transform.position);
    if(distance < 10){
        Vector2 dir = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion qto = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);  
        Quaternion qto2 = Quaternion.Euler (qto.eulerAngles.x,
                                            qto.eulerAngles.y,
                                            qto.eulerAngles.z + 90);  

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, qto2, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I'm Just Add qto2 and Slerp to that.

Comment: very nice, I changed +90 to -90 in qto2, now works !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
float turnspeed=1.0f;

//set a turning speed    
void Update () 
{        
    dir = player.position - transform.position;
    dir.Normalize();
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), turnSpeed *Time.deltaTime);                
}
```

Comment: I can't use `Quaternion.LookRotation()` because is a 2D game.